# vb.net disable runtime created buttons

Tags: vb.net, button, runtime, picturebox

Hey all i have created dynamic buttons at runtime and i would like to disable them when a user clicks on a form button.

This is the code i have for that button:

```
Dim intXX As Integer = 0

Do Until intXX = intX
    userAvatar(intXX).Enabled = False
    intXX = intXX + 1
Loop
```

The buttonNames is an array of all populated button names created at runtime. However, trying the .enabled = false at the end of that does not work. What other ways are there to do that with buttons created at runtime?

How i create the buttons are like this:

```
private sub createButton()
Dim personAvatar As New PictureBox

With personAvatar 
        .AutoSize = False                        '>                        ^

        If intX = 7 Then
            thePrviousAvatarImg = 0
        End If

        If intX <= 6 Then
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10 + thePrviousAvatarImg, 10)
        ElseIf intX >= 7 And intX <= 14 Then
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(10 + thePrviousAvatarImg, 150)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If

        .Name = "cmd" & nameOfPerson
        .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
        .TabStop = False
        .Text = ""
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
        .BackColor = Color.LightGray
        .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(theAvatarDir)
        .Tag = nameOfPerson
        .BringToFront()
    End With

    AddHandler personAvatar.Click, AddressOf personAvatar_Click
    Me.Controls.Add(personAvatar)
    userAvatar(intX) = personAvatar
    intX = intX + 1
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time and help!

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't refer to button objects using a string representation of their names. Instead of using `buttonNames` (which I assume is an array of strings), use an array of buttons and add each button to that. Then loop through that array (as you've done here) setting enabled = false on each one.

So before you create each picture box, declare an array to store them:

```
Dim MyPictureBoxes() as PictureBox
```

Then as you create each one, add them to the array. When you're done creating them, you can disable them like this:

```
For Each MyPictureBox In MyPictureBoxes
    Debug.Print(MyPictureBox.Name)
    MyPictureBox.enabled = False
Next
```

I've created a form with two buttons, cmdGo and cmdDisable, to demonstrate this more completely:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim MyPictureBoxes(4) As PictureBox

    Private Sub cmdGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdGo.Click
        Dim personAvatar As New PictureBox
        Dim intX As Integer = 0

        While intX < 5
            personAvatar = New PictureBox
            With personAvatar
                .AutoSize = False
                .Left = intX * 100
                .Top = 100
                .Name = "cmd" & intX
                .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 100)
                .TabStop = False
                .Text = ""
                .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center
                .BackColor = Color.LightGray
                .BringToFront()
            End With

            Me.Controls.Add(personAvatar)
            MyPictureBoxes(intX) = personAvatar
            intX = intX + 1
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdDisable_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDisable.Click
        For Each MyPictureBox In MyPictureBoxes
            Debug.Print(MyPictureBox.Name)
            MyPictureBox.Enabled = False
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Notice how `MyPictureBoxes` is scoped for the whole form so it's accessible to both subs.

Comment: @StealthRT Add the code where you generate the buttons to your question and that'll help me answer.

Comment: @StealthRT Updated my answer, give me a second to check that it actually works at my end.

Comment: Alright maybe i need to include some more info.. I want to be able to disable them after they are created. Meaning after they are created the user can do whatever on the form and if they hit a form button then it will disable those buttons in the array that have already been created.

Comment: And i also updated my OP to show that its a sub i call to create a button. It creates one button at a time whenever it calls to that sub. So i do not think i can do the array for something like that.

Comment: +1 This should work well.  I would consider using a List instead of an array, as in: Dim MyPictureBoxes = new List(Of PictureBox).  Then, in the original poster's code, adding the line: MyPictureBox.Add(personAvatar) will add each control to the list as it is created. The controls could still be accessed using the For Each loop shown in your answer.

Comment: @StealthRT just declare the array to be within scope of the form, not the sub. I've altered my answer to give you a more complete solution.

Comment: I get the following error on the line "Debug.Print(MyPictureBox.Name)" : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @StealthRT Click the cmdGo button to create the picture boxes, then click cmdDisable to disable them. If you click cmdDisable first it wont work. That's not really a great piece of code that I posted, it's just there to help with your understanding.

Comment: i updated my OP to show your code in it. Still get the error in my code.

Comment: @StealthRT I'm worried that you're copy/pasting without understanding what's going on, which will do more harm than good. Make sure you declare userAvatar in the same way I did, and make sure it's got enough room to hold all the PictureBoxes that you're creating. Do you understand what my code is doing?

Comment: yes, i created it using **Dim userAvatar(14) As PictureBox** which 14 is the max of buttons it will create. And i did put that at the very top **outside** the sub

Comment: @StealthRT Does IntX increment from 0 to 13 during the running of your sub? If it doesn't there will be empty slots in userAvatar which would cause that error. See how in my code it increments from 0 to 4. Your code needs to do something similar. You might also want to consider B Pete's solution of using a List instead of an array, especially if the number of PictureBoxes you have to store changes from time to time.

Comment: Ok i got it. OP updated to show. Saved how many **intX** there were and just looped until **intXX** reaches that :)